# How to implement a Security Token Service for an AWS Daemon in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are implementing a STS environment with Azure AD as the Identity Provider for Amazon Web Services applications running as a daemon/service in our datacenter that need to access our AWS resources. At this point using NodeJS with the wsfed2 library: https://github.com/auth0/passport-wsfed-saml2 We want our services to be able to acquire temporary AWS credentials based on the AWS STS Assume role with SAML api call.

This is how far we've gotten: Note: All Azure applications are described by their Application ID GUID.

1.-We were able to integrate the AWS CONSOLE with regular Users in our AZAD by following the documentation here(via browser only authentication): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-amazon-web-service-tutorial

2.-We were able to assume an AWS Role with SAML token based authentication to Azure(using web services based federation and the AWS Assume STS role API call with the STS token response from our Azure AWS STS application: and successfully login into a test NodeJS based Web application that pulls data from AWS.

3.-We followed the documentation listed here, to authenticate a Daemon application into a Service Application (using Windows .NET and microsoft ADAL over OAuth2.0) - This is OFFICIAL Microsoft documentation. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon

What we haven't accomplished:

4.-To get our TodoListDaemon appto be authenticated into our 'AWS STS QA' Azure application, since that Service application requires that a ROLE is assigned to each user, but in this case the user is not a person but a .NET service linked to the TodoListDaemon application which is registered into AAD. Instead we get the following error when running the ADAL sample code:

```
An error occurred while acquiring a token Time: 10/25/2017 2:45:17 AM Error: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS50105: Application '*******' is not assigned to a role for the application 'AWS STS QA'. Trace ID: d1cc4012-b0c1-4b8f-b3d4-325031ec0000 Correlation ID: 27543468-5087-44aa-9a86-336a2b0a81c9 Timestamp: 2017-10-25 02:45:17Z ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest). at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpClientWrapper.d__29.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.d__181.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__171.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__66.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__63.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__53.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__45.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__22.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at TodoListDaemon.Program.d__12.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Administrator\Source\Repos\active-directory-dotnet-daemon-withAWSService\TodoListDaemon\Program.cs:line 162 ErrorCode: invalid_grant StatusCode: 400 Retry: False'
```

4.1-To assign a role (as required by the error message above) the TodoListDaemon on the 'AWS STS QA'

```
application:https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ManagedAppMenuBlade/Permissions/objectId/*******/appId/******* [Problem start date and time] Wed, 18 Oct 2017 07:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: Is your daemon running on an Azure Virtual Machine? If so, then you won't be able to use AWS instance roles. Instead you will have to use identity credentials and emulate a login as a user inside your application.

Comment: No, All my infrastructure except for AD is on AWS. AD, which is on Azure is the blocker. AWS is to make a SSO call to AD using an STS role instead of uname and password.